# How to prevent Popup closing after date selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a popup with a `Datepicker` inside:

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox StaysOpen="True">  
     <DatePicker Focusable="False"/>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

When I select a date the `Datepicker` will close automatically, and also the Popup. How can I prevent the `Popup` closing when I select a date from the `Datepicker` inside the Popup?

As you can see I tried the property `StaysOpen` to true, but not seems to working, almost, not in this circumstance.

Comment: I'd like to test this, but where do I get materialDesign PopupBox from? Googled it a bit and there seems to be a lot of things with "material design" in the name.

Comment: @EdPlunkett is just an UI framework, you can download it via nuget or here: http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take `Focusable="False"` off the DatePicker, the PopupBox remains open when I select a date in the DatePicker.

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox StaysOpen="True">  
     <local:DatePicker2 />
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

C#

```
public class DatePicker2 : DatePicker 
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") is TextBox textBox)
        {
            textBox.IsReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

There you go, two answers for the price of one.

Comment: Uhm that's the problem, but there is a way for prevent the user to write custom date inside? this is the main reason why I added Focusable = false

Comment: "Uhm that's the problem"? Not sure what that means, but see update.